# How to make one AJAX call and receive several replies?

Tags: javascript, ajax

As the title says.

Basically, I have a webapp where the results of a call come in several parts which can take significantly different amounts of time to complete.

One way to do this is to make an asynchronous call and have the server send back the result only once it has all the parts of the response. However this way the whole response is as slow as the slowest of the response parts.

Another way would be to have the client make several independent requests each of which with its own independent callbacks being triggered by each of the response parts. This is better, but now I have a bunch of requests to the server instead of just 1. Unnecessary overhead here?

Yet another way would be to make just 1 call, but somehow have the several have several responses, one for each of the response parts finished.

Is this last idea possible? How?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, however i don't have any additional information to help toward the goal of accomplishing it unfortunately.

Comment: This could theoretically be done with websockets, although I think most people skipped ever using those because they require an entire server thread to be locked for the duration of the socket, which doesn't scale well.

Comment: @KevinB Do you have any references on a pattern that accomplishes this at all?

Comment: Nope. but, if it's possible to flush html content to the page incrementally (and it is), it must also be possible to do so with an xhr request. And, if not, could be worked around using an iframe to get the same result.

Comment: I'd say no, it's not possible with regular ajax, once the XMLHttpRequest receives the response the connection is generally closed, unless you use something like Comet (ajax push). Other options are sockets or polling, but you might as well just do multiple ajax calls for each dataset etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with HTTP. Client/server interactions with HTTP always follow a request/response pattern. Once the client receives a response, the connection is closed.

Websockets will be your best bet here. To my knowledge, websockets are the only way that a server can proactively send data to a client.